# Android Room Database size

Tags: android, android-room

I wanted to know what is the max size Room Database can take?. I don't see anything in the documentation.

Is there any option to set database size programmatically?

I have checked with documentation and couldn't find any info.

Answer (score 4):

Since Room is just an abstraction layer over SQLite. Room has the same limits as SQLite

> Maximum length of a string or BLOB Default size is 1 GB Max size is
>   2.147483647
>
> Maximum Number Of Columns Default size is 2000 Max size is 32767
>
> Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement Default size is 1 MB Max size is
>   1.073741824
>
> Maximum Number Of Tables In A Join Default is 64 tables
>
> Maximum Number Of Attached Databases Default is 10 Max size is 125
>
> Maximum Number Of Rows In A Table Max Size is 18446744073.709552765
>
> Maximum Database Size 140 tb but it will depends on your device disk
>   size.

from sqlite doc https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: But usually the device memory will not be in tb. So how can it be 140tb?

Comment: @KeerthiPrasadBV  Which means we can scale your database upto device storage size.

Answer (score 1):

I have wondered about the same. Since Room use SQLite underneath , here is what the SQLite database website has to say about the max size of SQLite database and its performance at huge sizes.

> Every database consists of one or more "pages". Within a single database, every page is the same size, but different database can have page sizes that are powers of two between 512 and 65536, inclusive. The maximum size of a database file is 2147483646 pages. At the maximum page size of 65536 bytes, this translates into a maximum database size of approximately 1.4e+14 bytes (140 terabytes, or 128 tebibytes, or 140,000 gigabytes or 128,000 gibibytes).
>
> This particular upper bound is untested since the developers do not have access to hardware capable of reaching this limit. However, tests do verify that SQLite behaves correctly and sanely when a database reaches the maximum file size of the underlying filesystem (which is usually much less than the maximum theoretical database size) and when a database is unable to grow due to disk space exhaustion.

I do not think any app will ever consume even a fraction of this size.

[SQLite limits](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Comment: I reached this limit; not about the size of the server but the amount of rows. 
I made a simple program to add like 10k rows to a DAO (SQLite) file. It works fine until it reaches the limit and crashes. So,would you know how to increase that value?